# How many marbles must be chosen to ensure having at least 3 of each

Tags: probability

there are 10 green marbles, 10 red marbles. How many marbles must be chosen to ensure having at least 3 of each colour?

Comment: What’s the largest number of marbles that you can choose *without* having at least $3$ of each color?

Comment: Try with the pigeonhole principle!

Comment: Anyway, the answer is $\geq$ 12.

Comment: @AlanTuring Technically the answer is $>12$ not $\ge 12$.

Comment: @WillFisher Mmm, well yes, I tried with a "brin" of optimism :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: You would by the least agree with me that the question itself is off-topic, because the OP does not show even one bit of effort answering it on his/her own... wouldn't you?

Comment: There are any ways in which you could have sai *that* while avoiding to be rude and, in fact, managing to be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to find the maximum number of marbles such that we don't have at least three of each color. Let $x$ be the number of green marbles and $y$ be the number of red marbles. We must have
$$(x\le 2)\lor(y\le 2)\qquad (1)$$
We want to maximize $x+y$ while keeping the above true. Consider when $(x\le 2)\land(y\le 2)$, which satisfies $(1)$, then $x+y\le 4$. Clearly this doesn't maximize $x+y$ because we could have $x=5$ and $y=2$ and still satisfy $(1)$ which gives $5+2=7\ge 4$. Thus we want
$$(x\le 2)\land(y>2)$$
which clearly satisfies $(1)$. We know by problem setup that $y\le 10$, so we can at most have $y=10$ and $x=2$ giving $x+y=12$. So if we have any more than $12$ marbles then we must have at least three of each color.

Comment: You have managed to confuse me.